# removeClass after hasClass isn't working

Tags: jquery

Do you know why using `removeClass` after `hasClass` give me `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`?

In code below, the alert won't be executed since the code above it produce an error..

```js
$("input[type='button']").hasClass("scroll").removeClass("inactive");
alert("success");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can anybody provide other way to achieve my goal?

Comment: hasclass() returns boolean, not jquery object

Comment: @Tommi why not post an answer?'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery `hasClass` returns boolean, which have no `removeClass` method. In your case it's much better to put class selector inside `$` call

```
$("input[type='button'].scroll").removeClass("inactive");
```

Comment: Take an upvote. It's better than having to check and then execute

Answer (score 5):

`.hasClass` check with if condition it returns boolean

```
if($("input[type='button']").hasClass("scroll")){
   $("input[type='button']").removeClass("inactive")
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the same thing as op asked. It will remove "inactive" class from ALL input type buttons if ANY of it has class "scroll". Additionally it's not optimal since you do `$("input[type='button']")` lookup twice.